# collection was modified enumeration operation may not execute. (no element added/removed)

Tags: vb.net, collections

I understand that a collection can't be modified while you iterate through it. However, I'm getting this exception message when iterating through a collection that NO element is being added or removed.

The code below does a simple check on dependencies between objects and returns true or false. However, it is not adding or deleting any element in the collection.

The exception is being thrown randomly. Has anyone experienced a similar issue where the "collection was modified enumeration operation may not execute" message/exception is not helpful?

code:

```
Public Function HasDependencies() As Boolean
    Dim attr As Attribute
    Dim dep As Attribute

    For Each attr In Me.Attributes
        If Not attr Is Me Then
            'not the attr we are currently on

            For Each dep In attr.AttributeDependencies
                If dep Is Me Then
                    'something depends on the current attr
                    Return True
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next

    Return False
End Function
```